# react hook form with Slider and Input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I need to get same value from Slider when I move it and from Input when I enter new value but it doesnt work correct

```
                            <StyledSlider
                            {register(NAMES.AMOUNT)}
                            defaultValue={5000}
                            value={typeof value === 'number' ? value : 5000}
                            min={5000}
                            max={50000}
                            onChange={handleSliderChange(NAMES.AMOUNT)}
                        />
                        <StyledLabel>
                            <StyledInput
                            {register(NAMES.AMOUNT)}
                                value={value}
                                onChange={handleInputChange(NAMES.AMOUNT)}
                                onBlur={handleBlur}
                                disableUnderline={true}
                            />
```

Answer (score 0):

The range input's value type is a string, and you have set up a type check with a fallback for `5000`.

If the state handling is set up properly, you only have to use `value={value}`.

Check out the related MDN page [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/range#value).